Try enable Nvidia GPU accelaration for chromium's video encoding
I build the latest Chromium 133, and tring enable Nvidia (3060 / 3090) hardware encoding.
./chrome --enable-features=AcceleratedVideoDecodeLinuxZeroCopyGL,AcceleratedVideoDecodeLinuxGL,VaapiIgnoreDriverChecks,VaapiOnNvidiaGPUs,AcceleratedVideoEncode

The run parameter come from Chrome Flags' Latest 2024 Update, Web Browser Video Hardware Acceleration on Linux.
There's only H.264 hardware encoding. I searched the web some days and can not find how to enable others: hevc / vp8 / vp9 / av1.

Also there are some warnnings / errors:
[320599:320616:1206/180421.367302:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(877)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
[320561:320561:1206/180423.122205:ERROR:fm_registration_token_uploader.cc(186)] Client is missing for kUser scope
[320561:320561:1206/180423.122224:ERROR:fm_registration_token_uploader.cc(186)] Client is missing for kUser scope
Warning: remove_all_non_valid_override_layers: Failed to get executable path and name
Warning: loader_scanned_icd_add: Could not get 'vkCreateInstance' via 'vk_icdGetInstanceProcAddr' for ICD libGLX_nvidia.so.0
Warning: loader_get_json: Failed to open JSON file intel_hasvk_icd.x86_64.json
Warning: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
Warning: loader_icd_scan: Failed loading library associated with ICD JSON /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so. Ignoring this JSON
Warning: loader_get_json: Failed to open JSON file lvp_icd.x86_64.json
Warning: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
Warning: loader_icd_scan: Failed loading library associated with ICD JSON /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so. Ignoring this JSON
Warning: vkCreateInstance: Found no drivers!
Warning: vkCreateInstance failed with VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER
    at CheckVkSuccessImpl (../../third_party/dawn/src/dawn/native/vulkan/VulkanError.cpp:106)

Warning: Couldn't find an EGLConfig rendering to a window for TextureFormat::RGBA8Unorm.
 - While trying to discover a BackendType::OpenGL adapter.
    at Initialize (../../third_party/dawn/src/dawn/native/opengl/ContextEGL.cpp:83)

I'm not sure these warnnings / errors related with the false hardware accelation?

Note 1: Nvidia driver version is 550.


The latest builds are nightly builds which aren't stable. Why not build the latest stable version instead? You can find the version information here: https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/releases?platform=Windows
